# Call netezza query from Visual Studio 2008' Execute SQL Task

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis, netezza

I pass a parameter into the Execute SQL Task tool in Visual Studio 2008 and i need to execute the follow:

```
DECLARE CurrentFileName  VARCHAR(200) :=  (?);  
DECLARE TableToTruncate VARCHAR(200); 
TableToTruncate   := CurrentFileName+'_TABLE_VAR';  
BEGIN 
TRUNCATE TABLE TableToTruncate;  
END;
```

Anyone have any idea why i keep getting

```
error    ^ found "DECLARE" (at char 1) expecting a keyword".
```

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion here is to create a stored procedure and call that on your SQL Task like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_truncate_table(@filename VARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE TableToTruncate VARCHAR(200); 
TableToTruncate   := @filename+'_TABLE_VAR';  

TRUNCATE TABLE TableToTruncate;  
END;
```

Then in `Execute SQL Task` configuration editor, in `SQLStatement` property say `exec sp_truncate_table ?`

See this [Article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/) for more information on the same.

Comment: Thanks Rahul however i am still getting error          
^ found "DECLARE" (at char 7) expecting a keyword"

Comment: That's not a proper way of plumbing query in SSIS sql task. See edited answer.